# Django cant find static(css) folder

Tags: django, django-templates, django-settings

My Django template cant seem to find my css file in my static folder which is structured at the root dir.

Here is my settings.py

```
from pathlib import Path

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-j@g&qm&20_oct_3f*sn-7n117si&1x4+m9cjao%g_&88gtmk9&'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'maintenance',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'nitrofleet.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR/'templates'],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'nitrofleet.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [ BASE_DIR/'static']
STATIC_ROOT = ["static_root"]
# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

and my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.urls.conf import include 
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('maintenance/',include('maintenance.urls'))
]


if settings.DEBUG :
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root =settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

and my template (also settings in the root dir) :

```
{%load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/styles.css' %}" />
</head>
<body>
   <div class='test'> turn this red </div
</body>
</html>
```

lastly the css file (setting in the root dir as static > css > styles.css)

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.sidebar{
    width: 70px;
    background-color: #73879c;
}

.test{
    color:red;
}
```

on making a get request ill receive this :

```
[15/Dec/2021 12:36:37] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1902
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of STATICFILES_DIR = [ BASE_DIR/'static']

Try using

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, '/static') ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your settings.py:

```
STATIC_ROOT = ["static_root"]
```

To this (of course, if your static folder name is "static"):

```
STATIC_ROOT = BASEDIR / "static"
```

In STATIC_ROOT you should set:
**BASEDIR + folder name, where your static files are.**

Comment: sadly same error, 
[15/Dec/2021 12:50:17] "GET /static/css/styles.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1902

Answer (score 0):

STATICFILES_DIR = [ BASE_DIR/'static']

here you has to finish line with comma, because is a list

STATICFILES_DIR = [
BASE_DIR/'static',
]